# VBA, MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 parse in head section

Tags: vba

I use this to get the webpage

```
Dim xhr As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set xhr = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

On Error Resume Next

With xhr

    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .send

    If .ReadyState = 4 And .Status = 200 Then
        Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText

        htmlRequestHTTP = True
    Else
        MsgBox "Internet Error, please check:" & vbNewLine & "Ready state: " & .ReadyState & _
        vbNewLine & "HTTP request status: " & .Status
        htmlRequestHTTP = False
    End If

End With
```

But doc.getElementsByTagName("META") misses the tags from HEAD section.
Now the .response is complete (I checked) so how can I access HEAD elemnts?
Thanks,

Comment: What does `responseText` contain? If the meta tags are in the HTML source, `doc.getElementsByTagName("META")` should work.

Comment: the .responsetext contains all I need but with doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText, the doc appears with empty HEAD

Comment: `doc.body` <-- you're referencing the body of the document and asking why you can't see the head section. Use the document object directly instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't write to the document body. Write to the document itself.

```
Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
doc.write HttpGet(URL)
MsgBox doc.getElementsByTagName("META").length
```

Helper function `HttpGet`:

```
Function HttpGet(url) As String
    With New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
        .open "GET", url, False
        On Error Resume Next
        .send
        If .Status = 200 Then
            HttpGet = .responseText
        Else
            MsgBox "HTTP request status: " & .Status, , "HttpGet Error"
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Function
```

As a general tip, don't use `On Error Resume Next` *except* for the very next statement.

Ideally, wrap statements that can fail in a dedicated function to keep the areas of code that are covered by `On Error Resume Next` to an absolute minimum, like I did.

Comment: doc.write() did the trick, thanks a lot. I already tried to assign doc = .response without success. Thanks also for the tip with error handling. One more note for VBA users like I am: If you receive a message "Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic" the doc passed by reference must be declared a Object -> ByRef doc As Object not as MSXML2.DOMDocument.

Comment: @Tomalak I encountered an error at this line `doc.write`