# Concatenate referenced URL into XML HTTP Request

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, concatenation

The following snippet of code sends a XML request to the following site

```
Sub GetContents()
   
            Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
            
            XMLReq.Open "Get", "https://echa.europa.eu/brief-profile/-/briefprofile/100.028.723", False
            XMLReq.send

End Sub
```

I have another Sub routine `GetURL()` which prints out the desired URL in this case: `https://echa.europa.eu/brief-profile/-/briefprofile/100.028.723`

How can I essentially concatenate the output of GetURL() into the BstrUrl? i.e.

`XMLReq.Open "Get", "x", False` where x is the output of GetURL()

Despite various attempts the syntax is not accepted as a URL.

Comment: Is GetURL() a function which returns a string?  Does it take any parameters?

Comment: You need to provide the code for GetURL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are combining from your earlier question then you need to ensure you write a function which returns the url (as Tim Williams has pointed out). I would expand upon this, in that I think you would need to consider adding a test to ensure both the request succeeded, there were results, and to pass the `searchKeyWord` as an argument to make your function more reusable. Along the same lines, you could pass the xmlhttp object into the function, so as to avoid continually creating and destroying them.

Avoid auto-instantiation, as you can get unexpected results, and Hungarian style notation.  Personally, I also avoid those type characters, as they are harder to read.

`vbNullString` will offer faster assignment than `= ""`.

I would also use a shorter, faster, and more reliable css pattern to retrieve the url, based on classes and a parent child relationship of two elements.

---

```
Public Sub GetContents()
    Dim searchKeyWord As String, xmlReq As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, url As String
    
    searchKeyWord = "Acetone"
    Set xmlReq = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    
    url = GetUrl(searchKeyWord, xmlReq)
    
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    If url <> "N/A" Then
    
        With xmlReq
            .Open "GET", url, False
            .send
            If .Status = 200 Then
                html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
                Debug.Print html.querySelector("title").innerText
            End If
        End With
       
    End If
    
End Sub


Public Function GetUrl(ByVal searchKeyWord As String, ByVal http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60) As String
 
    Const url = "https://echa.europa.eu/search-for-chemicals?p_auth=5ayUnMyz&p_p_id=disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_col_id=_118_INSTANCE_UFgbrDo05Elj__column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_javax.portlet.action=doSearchAction&_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_backURL=https%3A%2F%2Fecha.europa.eu%2Finformation-on-chemicals%3Fp_p_id%3Ddisssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet%26p_p_lifecycle%3D0%26p_p_state%3Dnormal%26p_p_mode%3Dview%26p_p_col_id%3D_118_INSTANCE_UFgbrDo05Elj__column-1%26p_p_col_count%3D1%26_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_sessionCriteriaId%3D"
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, dict As Object, i As Long, r As Long
    Dim dictKey As Variant, payload$, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    dict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_formDate") = "1621017052777" 'timestamp
    dict("_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_searchOccurred") = "true"
    dict("_disssimplesearch_WAR_disssearchportlet_sskeywordKey") = searchKeyWord
    dict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimer") = "true"
    dict("_disssimplesearchhomepage_WAR_disssearchportlet_disclaimerCheckbox") = "on"

    payload = vbNullString
    
    For Each dictKey In dict
        payload = IIf(Len(dictKey) = 0, WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(dictKey) & "=" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(dict(dictKey)), _
                      payload & "&" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(dictKey) & "=" & WorksheetFunction.EncodeURL(dict(dictKey)))
    Next dictKey
    
    With http
        .Open "POST", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send (payload)
        If .Status = 200 Then
            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        Else
            GetUrl = "N/A"
            Exit Function
        End If
    End With
    
    Dim result As Boolean
    
    result = html.querySelectorAll(".lfr-search-container  .substanceNameLink").Length > 0
    
    GetUrl = IIf(result, html.querySelector(".lfr-search-container  .substanceNameLink").href, "N/A")
End Function
```

Comment: Loved the way you implemented the boolean logic.

Comment: "@QHarr Hi there, when I copy all this code as exact into a new module and then run the GetContents() sub nothing is returned. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try this `Html.querySelector("#substanceIdentifiersContainer > h2").innerText` instead of `Html.querySelector("title").innerText`. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29323128/9189799) might help you why you could not get data from head.

Comment: Thank you. No worries if not but do you you think you could help me out if I wanted to do this using the browser automation route to get the URL? Don't get me wrong I'm grateful for you help both of your have provided, I'm just like to understand the code in case something goes wrong and I have to update. Ultimately I will use the answers you have provided when I understand them.

Comment: I will have a look later today. I thought you already pretty much have the code that automates a browser a returns the link? I thought I saw that in one of your earlier questions? The question now is whether you will be using this, now and then, to return the odd url, or whether you will be processing lists of start urls at a time?

Comment: Yeah I have just managed to get it working with the browser however Its not as reliable as I would like. So I am still looking at implementing the XMLmethod you have both provided but Still run into issues. @SIM I did add that change and strangely the only result that is printed in the immediate window is the keyword Acetone

Comment: I have just tested the above code with Debug.Print html.body.innerHTML = .responseText and the result returned is false. Looks like something is missing? Though im no expert.

Comment: If I run the code, as is, it returns `Acetone - Substance Information - ECHA`. Have you changed the code?

Comment: Hm I apologise If I have confused you. Please could you see my update at the end to see how I am trying to incorporate the Answer from @SIM which  pulls the Url and then run my sub routine to pull the date from this url. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Also Apologies for taking up your time, it is appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Nick, I'll give this a look tomorrow. I think QHarr will come up with any solution by then. Thanks.

Comment: Nick - you should roll-back the edit. Then post a new question with this new question.

Comment: Sorry @QHarr, I didn't notice there was an edit from OP's end after your answer.

Comment: @SIM No worries.

Comment: @Qharr I've rolled it back and posted the edit as a new question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If `GetURL` is a function returning a string then this should work:

```vb
Sub GetContents()
   
    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim url

    url = GetURL()

    XMLReq.Open "Get", url, False
    XMLReq.send

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer, unfortunately I get an error saying that the parameter is incorrect. The `GetURL()` function does print the correct Url but `XMLReq,open "get, url, False` is not accepted.

Comment: Did you confirm that the value of `url`  is a valid address?

Comment: Please ignore my chat, I understand what you mean now and its working